# Android Facebook SDK SSO Logcat "Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider"

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I have this error in Logcat

> Failed to find provider info for
>   com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider

When I use Virtual device the app seems to ignore this error and I am able to login facebook.
However if I run the app on a device, then Login dialogue does not appear, just a white screen.
I have tried to run key hash many times and I do not think this caused the errors

Anyone could help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code snippets on how you're calling the Facebook SDK? Usually this error means that the Facebook app is not installed on the device, but it should still fall back to using the web dialog. Are you seeing the web dialog pop up when using the emulator?

Comment: Are you running a sample from the Facebook SDK, or are you running your own application?

Comment: Any update? I've got the same issue now.

Answer (score 3):

This message means that Facebook app is not installed on your device.